# Page content formatting

Tags: tables, formatting, positioning

So have found some issues with page content placing. It never happen to me before. So I have 3 pages of text and one table (which is 1 page length). These all pages are two sections. First section is 2 text pages and table, and other section is 1 page of text. Every page is one page length (I mean it is fully written page of symbols). And I don't know how all 3 text pages goes first, leaving table in 4 page. So my sections are messed up. Maybe any one could lend me some ideas, how to move my table from page 4 to it's right position in  page 3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: put `\clearpage` after the table or don't use the `table` environment.

Comment: [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275)